# How to have Sobel edge detection ignore NaN or 0

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have an image in which half of the image is blacked out by either NaN's or zeroes (I can choose which one or put any other value in that half of the image) and I want to do Sobel edge detection on the entire image while having it ignore the line formed by the transition from NaN/0 to the actual image. Here's an example of the image I want to do edge detection on:

[image]

I would just do edge detection on the right side of the image, but later on in my project, I will have a curved shape instead of a nice rectangular one so there will be some NaN/0's no matter how I crop it.

When I do edge detection right now I get:
[image]

So basically my questions boils down to: Is there any way for me to remove that edge that was detected in the middle or to have Sobel somehow ignore that type of transition?

I'm also confused as to why Sobel detects the line in the middle of the image but not the lines on the side created when I rotated the image which caused some pixels on the edge to be filled with 0's. I think it's because those edges are not connected to any prominent edges, but that doesn't help me very much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Yes, the image is that of a fruit fly.

Comment: Just do it with NaNs, then do your thresholding, then convert the NaNs to binary zeros. I'm not understanding your issue?

Comment: Are you sure its Sobel? Looks like a Canny edge detection to me.

Comment: @kosinix: what makes you say that ?

Answer (score 1):

The edges detected along the invalid area will be confined in a 3x3 neighborhhod. Just erase those pixels using the original image as a mask (with dilation).

Answer (score 0):

You can first crop your image, do the edge filter and then pad the result with zeros.